# PHP Regex returns array of 2 identical strings

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string and Regex:

```
$string = 'xxx-zzzzzz-xxx';
preg_match('/(?<=xxx-)(.*)(?=-xxx)/', $string, $extract);

var_dump($extract);
```

This outputs:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'zzzzzz' (length=6)
  1 => string 'zzzzzz' (length=6)
```

Why do I get an array size of 2 since the matched string only appears once? And how would I do to get only a string or an array with 1 string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index=0` is whole match and `index=1` (and onwards) is first captured group. If you don't want captured group then just use:

```
/(?<=xxx-).*(?=-xxx)/
```

i.e.

```
preg_match('/(?<=xxx-).*(?=-xxx)/', $string, $extract);
print_r($extract);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> If `$matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

In other words, `matches[0]` returns the full match, with other keys in the array returning only partial matches (equal to the number of `()` used in your regular expression).

Keep in mind that preg_match will only ever match one complete result; if you want to return all matches in a given string, have a look at [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.